# get 3 value of selected radio | JS

Tags: javascript

I have 4 radio in my html . the user must select 3 radio .
i know how to get the value of 1 radio. but if the selected radio value is 3 radio, i do not know how to do it .

```
<div class="radio"  data-value="A" />
<div class="radio"  data-value="B" />
<div class="radio"  data-value="C" />
<div class="radio"  data-value="D" />
```

JS

```
$('.radio').click(function () {
    var type  = $(this).attr('data-value');
 });
```

Comment: Radio buttons are intended for you to select one option only. Maybe you should consider using inputs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From their definition in wikipedia

> A radio button or option button is a graphical control element that allows the user to choose **only one** of a predefined set of mutually exclusive options.
>
> A checkbox (check box, tickbox, tick box) is a GUI widget that permits the user to make a binary choice, i.e. a choice between one of two possible mutually exclusive options.

So if you have to select 3 choices, you must use **checkbox** instead of radio button.

This is a simple example of checkbox. Hope it helps.

```js
$('input').click(function () {
    var checked  = $('input:checked');
    checked.each((index, itm) => {
      console.log(itm.value);
    });
    console.log('-----------');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle3" value="Boat"> I have a boat<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle3" value="plane"> I have a plane<br>
```

---

**Update**

With `div` element you should create an array of selected items. Something like this:

```js
var selectedArr = [];

$('.radio').click(function() {
  var type = $(this).attr('data-value');
  var index = selectedArr.findIndex(a => {
    return a == type;
  });
  if(index == -1) {
    selectedArr.push(type);
    console.log('item added');
  }
  else {
    selectedArr.splice(index, 1);
    console.log('item removed');
  }
  console.log(selectedArr);
  console.log('---------------------');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio" data-value="A"> A </div>
<div class="radio" data-value="B"> B </div>
<div class="radio" data-value="C"> C </div>
<div class="radio" data-value="D"> D </div>
```

---

**Update 2**

```js
var var1, var2, var3, var4;

$('.radio').click(function() {
  var type = $(this).attr('data-value');
  var flag = checkVal(var1, type);
  (flag)? (flag == 1)? var1 = type : var1 = undefined : '';
  if(flag) return logger();
  
  flag = checkVal(var2, type);
  (flag)? (flag == 1)? var2 = type : var2 = undefined : '';
  if(flag) return logger();
  
  flag = checkVal(var3, type);
  (flag)? (flag == 1)? var3 = type : var3 = undefined : '';
  if(flag) return logger();
  
  flag = checkVal(var4, type);
  (flag)? (flag == 1)? var4 = type : var4 = undefined : '';
  if(flag) return logger();
});

function logger () {
  console.log({
      'var1': var1,
      'var2': var2,
      'var3': var3,
      'var4': var4
    });
}

function checkVal(x, y) {
  if (x) {
    if (x == y) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio" data-value="A"> A </div>
<div class="radio" data-value="B"> B </div>
<div class="radio" data-value="C"> C </div>
<div class="radio" data-value="D"> D </div>
```

Comment: not work . see i am not using "input" element , i am using "div"

Comment: the problem in this line".radio:checked" i have to change checked to anything else

Comment: Check the update, @NodyNody You dont have `checked` attritbute in `div` element.

Comment: one Q, if i want to save each data-value slected in new one var , how ? couse i want to make serach in database depend on these selected

Comment: In this solution you store them in array and if number of `radio`s changed, you don't need any change. In that case, you should create variables the number of `div`s and assign the selected item to its variable. @NodyNody

Comment: can u give example

Comment: Check update2 @NodyNody but it has some errors also and is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.radio').click(function(){
var value = []; // initialize empty array 
       $(".radio:checked").each(function(){
        value.push($(this).val());
        }); 
       alert(value);

       });
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="radio"  value="A" />
<input type="radio" class="radio"  value="B" />
<input type="radio" class="radio"  value="C" />
<input type="radio" class="radio"  value="D" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: not work . see i am not using "input" element , i am using "div"

Comment: the problem in this line".radio:checked" i have to change checked to anything else